# Is it permissible to connect 3.3V powered devices to the 5V I2C bus?

Tags: i2c

I have several devices on the I2C bus:

1. RTC [DS3231SN](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/DS3231-1513891.pdf)
2. [TMP100](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmp100.pdf) temperature sensor
3. EEPROM [24LC256](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21203N.pdf)

All devices are powered by 3.3V. The voltage on the I2C bus is 5V.

**Question:**
Is the voltage difference on the bus and device power normal?

Comment: It's better to use level translator. Or you can try to power pull-ups from 3.3V, it usually works, but 3.3V CMOS output interfacing 5V CMOS logic input isn't 100% compatible as some devices might need almost 3.5V to detect high level.

Comment: KIIV, Thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you using the bare chips, or do you have breakout board. If the latter, the problem might be with Arduino enabling the internal pull-up resistors inside the MCU. The breakouts already have pull-up resistors on them, so the Arduino board shouldn't do that (but does). Usually it doesn't matter, and help with people using bare chips, and forgetting to add pull-up resistors on the I2C lines. To disable them; see https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13448/disabling-i2c-internal-pull-up-resistors . After that the I2C lines should read 3.3V instead of 5V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3.3V devices that have 5V-tolerant inputs; that may be the case for your devices, but I would not risk it. Use a level converter designed for I2C, such as https://www.adafruit.com/product/757. Or you can make your own; https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf explains how such a level converter works. Use a BSS138 if you are comfortable with soldering SMT components; otherwise use a 2N7000.

Comment: JayEye, 
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: For the DS3231 the maximum voltage if `Vcc+0.3V`. The TMP100 seems to allow up to `6V` regardless of Vcc. The 24L256's maximum is `Vcc+1.0V`